# MS Access VBA: how do I clear Image control?

Tags: image, ms-access, vba

I have an Image control that reads a file from disk as the user navigates. If there is no file (an empty field), I need to erase the previous image. The [microsoft page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/80488) says to do as follows:

```
Sub Form_Click ()
    picture1.picture = LoadPicture()
End Sub
```

But when I do it, Access complains that "the argument is not optional"! I also tried `LoadPicture("")` as stated [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=62323) and [here](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=762333), to no avail. It says "Microsoft Access can't open the file '0'." How can I clear the picture in runtime? I'm using Access 2002. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following:

```
picture1.picture = ""
```